# Eventual Periodicity in a Representation of a Rational 2-adic Integer

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

Let $x$ be a rational $2$-adic integer (i.e., an eventually repeating sequence of zeros and ones). Define the strictly increasing sequence $n_k$ of non-negative integers by the equation

$$x = -\sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{2^{n_k}}{3^{k+1}}$$

This can be done inductively by defining $2^{n_0}$ to be the largest power of two that divides $x$. Then, if

$$x_m = -\sum_{k=0}^m \dfrac{2^{n_k}}{3^{k+1}}$$

we define $n_{m+1}$ to be the place of the first digit such that $x_m$ and $x$ differ in their $2$-adic expansions. This works because $-3^{-k-1}$ is always odd (first digit is one). Now, let $d_k = n_{k+1} - n_k$ be the sequence of differences.

**Question**: Is the sequence $d_k$ eventually periodic?

Or, equivalently, define the $2$-adic integer $y$ to have the digit $1$ in each place $n_k$ and $0$ elsewhere (i.e., $y = \sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{n_k}$). Is $y$ rational?

**Example**: Take $x = -5$. Then, $x = \cdots 111011_2$, and we have

$$x = -\dfrac{1}{3} - \dfrac{2}{3^2} - \dfrac{2^3}{3^3} - \dfrac{2^4}{3^4} - \dfrac{2^6}{3^5} - \dfrac{2^7}{3^6} - \cdots$$

so that $y = \cdots 011011011011_2$, i.e., $y = -3/7$.

**Motivation**: If $x$ is odd, multiply by three and add one.

**Update**: Consider different series expansions of the same number, e.g.,

$$-\dfrac{1}{3} - \dfrac{2}{9} - \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{2^{2k+5}}{3^{k+3}} = 3 = -\sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{2^{2k}}{3^k}$$

While the second series doesn't have the exact same form (the first power of $3$ is $0$ instead of $1$), they are similar in their tails. Might it be possible to show that, if there exists an expansion, such as on the right, that is rational -- in the sense of above -- then the series on the left (the one of interest) is also rational -- in the sense of above?

Comment: I have two questions about your post: 1) what do you mean by asking "is the sequence $d_k$ eventually repeating"? Are you asking if for a general $x \in \mathbb{Z}_2$ then there always exist to positive integers $i,j$ such that $d_i=d_j$, or on the contrary there exists such an $x$ such that all the $d_k$ are different? 2) What do you mean with "$y$ is rational" in the last line? I mean, if $y=\sum_k 2^{n_k}$ then either the series on the right hand side does not converge (hence $y$ is not defined at all), or the series converges in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and [continues]

Comment: $y$ is a well defined element of the $2$-adic integers. To be an element of $\mathbb{Q}_2$ you should admit some of the integers $n_k$ to be negative.

Comment: @N.B. The sequence $d_k$ is eventually repeating if there are $N, t \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d_k = d_{k+t}$ for all $k \geq N$. In other words, if the sequence ends in a repeating pattern.

Comment: @N.B. What I meant by "rational" is that the integer has an eventually repeating $2$-adic representation.

Comment: @Torsten Schoeneberg The term "rational $p$-adic integer" used to describe the $p$-adic expansion of a rational real number (which is eventually repeating) is common in both textbooks and research papers. I will post more examples and motivation when I get a chance later tonight.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I misunderstood what you were saying and have changed the term used. I have added an example and a blurb about motivation. Also, I think it's pretty obvious that the other direction holds: if $y$ is rational, then $x$ is rational. I'd post attempts, but honestly I have no idea how to even start. Let me know if you'd like more examples; they're pretty easy to generate.